# Interactive Python Interpreter Run in Background

Tags: python, linux, bash

I've run into a weird problem when starting an interactive python console in the background. After resuming the interpreter from the background, it does not display any of the text I type (i.e. it just shows the >>> prompt, though it will interpret whatever I write.  Pressing [enter] created another >>> prompt on the same line).

An easy way to reproduce the problem is just to type:

```
python &
fg
```

This problem does does not occur if you start the program in the foreground, put it in the background, and return it to the foreground:

```
python
[ctrl-z]
bg
fg
```

If you're wondering why you might want to start an interactive interpreter in the background, consider the following scenario:

I have a simulation that takes a long time to run, but after it's done, I want to interact with the results.  Thus, I started the program:

```
python -i simulation.py &
fg #(after it's finished running)
```

The easy solution is just to start it in the foreground, move it to the background, and then later bring it to the foreground, but I'm just wondering why this happens.

Comment: Do you have the `readline` module installed? I've seen similar behavior with `readline` while it's built against BSD `libedit` instead of GNU `libreadline`. Although not for quite a few years… Which distro/version, which Python version, and, while we're at it, which shell and terminal program and versions?

Comment: Also, does `simulation.py` do anything with `termios`, `tty`, `curses`, or similar, or write binary data to the terminal?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 13.04, Python 2.7, and Bash.  The script doesn't do any of the things you listed, but I'm not sure that's relevant, since you can reproduce the problem even without a script (python &).

Comment: FWIW, python3 has the same problem.

Comment: Bash version 4.2.45(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: I can reproduce this on CentOS (bash 3.2.25), but not OS X (bash 3.2.48).

Comment: @sheridp: You didn't mention the terminal program. But I'm assuming it's whatever Ubuntu 13.04 defaults to (gnome-terminal maybe?). Anyway, I'm pretty sure Ubuntu uses libreadline, not editline, and everything seems more than new enough that the bug I used to have to deal with in OS X 10.4 wouldn't be likely to be affecting you… But in the future, please answer all of the questions—not just Python 2.7 but 2.7.2 or 2.7.5 or whatever, and the name and version of the terminal program.

Comment: By the way, your 'easy solution' does not work for me. I still have the same problem you describe. Will now try the suggestions in the anwers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider executing the following commands to force the terminal ECHO mode after you have brought your interpreter into the foreground:

```
import termios
attr = termios.tcgetattr(1)
attr[3] = attr[3] | termios.ECHO
termios.tcsetattr(1, termios.TCSANOW, attr)
```

Comment: Any idea why the terminal ECHO attribute gets unset?

Comment: Essentially the same as your solution:  import os; os.system('reset') or os.system('stty sane').  Still not sure why local echo gets disabled though.  Also interesting, executing reset or stty sane from outside the interpreter (with python in bg) does not solve the problem.